# PHP Regex to disallow lines start with ~$

Tags: php, regex

This is the code that I've created;

```
$abs = preg_grep('/^\~\$/gmi', $files);
var_dump($abs);
$json = json_encode($files);
echo($json);
```

Could anybody explain why it's not catching the second item in the following variable?

```
["Renewal Fee Reminder.docx","~$newal Fee Reminder.docx"]
```

edit:

Fixed, code is as follows (although only checks the first character);

```
$files = file_list($templateDir, '.docx');

function sortLineStarters($var) {
    return !($var[0] == '~');
}

$sortedFiles = array_filter($files, "sortLineStarters");

$json = json_encode($sortedFiles);
echo($json);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using regular expressions for that?

```
strpos($line, "~$") !== 0
```

would do the trick while being much more readable.

As for the regular expression itself:

- I don't think the modifier `g` is supported. See [the list of supported modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for more information.
- You don't need a backslash before "~".
- You don't need case insensitive flag, since the two characters you use don't depend on the case.

Comment: This seems to be the answer for my question, although I found a slightly different way yours is better! I was going to use regex to be able to match more things in the future but I can get away without that. Thanks! edit - again, I added the case insensitive flag due to futureproofing. I guess it shouldn't be in there for now though!

Comment: @HarryTorry: follow [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it): if you don't need something right now, don't do it. This being said, I've edited my answer to add a possible reason why the regular expression doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: I've never heard of YAGNI, KISS is something I tend to forget as well. YAGNI is now on a post it attached to my screen. Cheers for the help though!

Comment: @HarryTorry: you're welcome. Also, I've edited my answer once again; make sure to check the first point in the list.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems. Firstly, `g` is an unknown modifier. Here is a list of all the valid php pattern modifiers: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Secondly, the `$` in `"~$newal Fee Reminder.docx"` needs to be escaped. If not php will look for a variable named `$newal` and try to insert into the string.

The following code should work:

```
$files = ["Renewal Fee Reminder.docx","~\$newal Fee Reminder.docx"];
$abs = preg_grep('/^~\$/mi', $files);
```

**Edit**

If you want to match strings that do not start with `~$` then use the regex `/^[^~][^\$]/mi`

Comment: Thanks! I'm used to JS regex where the g is supported!